# How to create responsive table in which schema of table changes on break point using bootstrap or without bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, bootstrap-5, responsive-table

I want to create a table which will get changed its schema on mobile screen breakpoint.

**On big screen like laptop table should look like this:**

| Email | Degination | Team | Last Active | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alok@something.com | Manager | Sales | 2022-06-20 | India |
| amit@something.com | Manager | Sales | 2022-06-19 | USA |

**On mobile screen table should look like this:**

| alok@something.com |
| --- |
| **Degination** Manager |
| **Team** Sales |
| **Last Active** 2022-06-20 |
| **Location** India |

| amit@something.com |
| --- |
| **Degination** Manager |
| **Team** Sales |
| **Last Active** 2022-06-19 |
| **Location** USA |

I dont want to mantain two `<tables>`/`<div>` for these two table views of same content.

How can I make single `<table>` which can show these two different views based on screen size?

Comment: Please try this - https://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/DZxEKy and also, https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/mBQoOj Hope, this help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap5 in your HTML you can use `table-responsive` class name in your `<table>` tag.
Please refer this link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#always-responsive

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use 2 tables, maybe a css style to apply to the existing table based on the screen size,

something like this

```
table {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
tbody {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: row;
}
tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
thead{
  display: none;
}
```

and a working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/c37none/5u6zfe2n/1/

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for.